# Error installing grunt-sass

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to install grunt-sass using npm, according to what is said [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass), running the following command

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-sass
```

It happens that I'm receiving an error message:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY grunt@>=0.4.0
```

and then again

```
npm WARN grunt-contrib-sass@1.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-sass@1.2.0 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
```

But when I run

```
grunt --version
```

I get the following result

```
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v0.4.5
```

This says I have grunt 0.4.5 and it requires only 0.4.0, so it should be working fine.

Any suggestions about what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all got resolved when I intalled the gem sass. All I had to do was

```
gem install sass
```

and then

```
grunt build
```

It seems there is a dependency here, but it says nothing in the error message to help one find this out. A documentation problem, more than a bug.